# Can't load assets in Laravel project when setting up a self-signed SSL reverse proxy with Docker

Tags: docker, nginx, laravel-5, openssl, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to setup HTTPS for my ***dev*** Laravel project, as I'd like to use Facebook login (this requires HTTPS for ***dev*** environments too now)

I'm following this tutorial: https://medium.com/@oliver.zampieri/self-signed-ssl-reverse-proxy-with-docker-dbfc78c05b41

It basically says the following:

Create the self signed certificate:

```
openssl req -subj '/CN=my-sitename.development' -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Find route to the host:
Docker runs containers in their own sandbox, so, when the containers run in a bridged network, we need to know what is the IP address of the host (if we route to localhost or 127.0.0.1 we would proxy back into the container, instead, we need to route to the host machine)

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

=> This gives us 172.17.0.1

Now create the NginX configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 443;

    # I've added this myself
    server_name my-sitename.development;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/conf.d/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/conf.d/key.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1;
    }
}
```

Run the Docker container

```
docker run --name nginx_proxy -d -v `pwd`:/etc/nginx/conf.d -p 443:443 nginx
```

Last but not least I've added my created certificate in my Mac Keychain and set it to "always trust".

When I open up my (https) local site in my browser (Chrome v67), then it tells me that the certificate is valid and the website is working (I can see my site-text etc ..) except for the assets.

The request for the assets looks like this: 
I don't think this can be right, but I'm not sure what to input for the proxy_pass config (see above). Entering my-sitename.development for the proxy_pass doesn't work. Then it redirects me to the default nginx page of the nginx_proxy docker container.

```
https://172.17.0.1/css/all.css
```

Please note: I have another nginx docker container running to handle requests to my-sitename.development:80

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! 
Didn't need to setup the extra Docker container after all ... 
Could just edit the nginx config of my existing Docker container (that handled the :80 connections)